# Reverse jquery animation using 2 different clicks?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to expand a div (#square) and then have some text (.squarecontent) fade in. Additionally I want there to be a a link that appears within #square to reverse the animation and fade. jfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9T54L/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.squarecontent').hide();

$('#square').click(function() {
$('#square').animate({
width: '100%',
height: '100%'
  },
  1000,
  function() {
      $('.squarecontent').fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
$('#bottomright').click(function() {
      $('.squarecontent').fadeOut(1000);
},
function () {
  $('#square').animate({
      width: '300px',
      height: '300px'
  },
  1000)
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way by adding a Opened flag and using `e.StopPropagation()` to stop the close event from triggering the open event when bubbling the DOM.

**See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9T54L/3/)**

Note: I changed your image to a link since the source was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in this way. `#bottomright` is a part of `#square` so clicking on `#bottomright` you also clicking on `#square`.

In this case both method (for hide and for show) are fired.

### Solution:

I see here 2 ways. You can move this img to outside `#square` or add one link/button which will toggle your animation.

---

Look on this example from jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/27uVs/

More information about `toggle()` you can find [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).